# Saving the value of custom field into sales_flat_order_address table

Tags: magento

I have a custom field(new_address_code) for customer address in backend. A observer is used to assign a auto-generated value to the field when ever a new address is added through myaddress or in checkout page

```
<customer_address_save_after>
      <observers>
         <myautoincrement>
            <class>samp/observer</class>
            <method>saveadrsmethod</method>
         </myautoincrement>
      </observers>
</customer_address_save_after>
```

In the observer class

```
$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
$id= (string)$customerAddress->getId();
$ObcustomerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
if ($customerAddress->getId()) {
            $customerAddress->setData('new_address_code','aftertesting-'.$customerAddress->getData('firstname').'=myid'.$id);
             $customerAddress->getResource()->saveAttribute($ObcustomerAddress, 'new_address_code');
   }
```

Whats the problem here is when a new address is added while checkout, the auto-generated custom fields value is not saved into sales_flat_quote_address table. So, I tried writing an observer for that as follows

```
<sales_order_place_before>
    <observers>
       <myautoincrement>
          <class>samp/observer</class>
          <method>beforeorder</method>
       </myautoincrement>
    </observers>
</sales_order_place_before>
```

And in the observer class

```
   public function beforeorder($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    if ($customerAddress->getId()) {
        $address=Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->setData('new_address_code',$customerAddress->getData('new_address_code'));
        $order->setBillingAddress($address);
        $order->setShippingAddress($address);
    }
}
```

But it's not saving in the sales_flat_order_address table. Could anybody tell me the correct way to do it.

Comment: I had siilar problems in the past and total Magento cache clearing solved the problem.

Comment: @ceckoslab I cleared the cache several times. I think it's not the problem. May be the code I have written in function beforeorder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have give a solution

event is

```
<checkout_submit_all_after>
    <observers>
        <auto_set_custom_field>
            <class>check/observer</class>
            <method>autosetBillingShipfield</method>
        </auto_set_custom_field>
    </observers>
</checkout_submit_all_after>
```

observer function code is

```
public function autosetBillingShipfield($Observer){
    $Order=$Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $Quote=$Observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if ($Quote->getBillingAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()&& !is_null($Order->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId())) {
                 $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load((int)$Order->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId());
        $SaleaOrderAdd=Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($Order->getBillingAddress()->getId());       
        $SaleaOrderAdd->setData('myaddr_new_code','after-testingnew-'.$Order->getBillingAddress()->getData('firstname').'--'.$address->getId());
        $SaleaOrderAdd->getResource()->saveAttribute($SaleaOrderAdd, 'myaddr_new_code');


    }
    if ($Quote->getShippingAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()&& !is_null($Order->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId())) {
                 $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load((int)$Order->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId());
        $SaleaShipOrderAdd=Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($Order->getShippingAddress()->getId());      

        $SaleaShipOrderAdd->setData('myaddr_new_code','after-testingnew-'.$Order->getShippingAddress()->getDataFirstname().'--'.$address->getId());
        $SaleaShipOrderAdd->getResource()->saveAttribute($SaleaShipOrderAdd, 'myaddr_new_code');

    }

}
```

Comment: I have a small doubt. how do we save the external id in the quote address table, in the same way or different way..